# C File Reader from array

Tags: c

I can see the last `printf` output of `y` but the `fpc` turns null.

I suspected for double quotes in `fopen` function but not could not find a solution: how to fix it?

**Part of the code ;**

```
char *y = &arr_lines[1024*2];

FILE *fpc = fopen(y, "r");

        if (fpc == NULL) {
                printf("Error opening file.\n");
                //return -1;
        }
printf("TEST %s\n",y);
```

When I run the code;

```
Error opening file.
TEST /Users/lessons/AbstractLesson.java
```

Here is the full code;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#define LINESIZE 1024
int main(void){

    char *arr_lines, *line;
    char buf_line[LINESIZE];
    int num_lines = 0;
    char buf[10240];

    // open file
    FILE *fp = fopen("/tmp/file", "r");
    //FILE *fp1 = fopen(arr_lines, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
            printf("Error opening file.\n");
            return -1;
    }
    // get number of lines; from http://stackoverflow.com/a/3837983
    while (fgets(buf_line, LINESIZE, fp))
            if (!(strlen(buf_line) == LINESIZE-1 && buf_line[LINESIZE-2] != '\n'))
                    num_lines++;
    // allocate memory
    arr_lines = (char*)malloc(num_lines * 1024 * sizeof(char));
    // read lines
    rewind(fp);
    num_lines = 0;
    line=arr_lines;
    while (fgets(line, LINESIZE, fp))
            if (!(strlen(line) == LINESIZE-1 && line[LINESIZE-2] != '\n'))
                    line +=  LINESIZE;
    // print first four lines
    char *y = &arr_lines[1024*2];

    FILE *fpc = fopen(y, "r");
        //FILE *fp1 = fopen(arr_lines, "r");
        if (fpc == NULL) {
                printf("Error opening file.\n");
                //return -1;
        }

printf("TEST [%s]\n",y);
     //x = &arr_lines[1024*0];
    // y = *x;

  // finish
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
```

}

Comment: Does `/Users/lessons/AbstractLesson.java` exist? Is it readable?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the file `/Users/lessons/AbstractLesson.java` exists and do you have read access to it?

Comment: yes file exists and its readable

Comment: Please include the exact output of `ls -la /Users/lessons/AbstractLesson.java` in your question.

Comment: What is the definition of `arr_lines` and how are you setting it?

Comment: You could inspect the error number to learn more about the actual problem: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html

Comment: Also, please change the `printf` to `printf("TEST [%s]\n",y);` and include the output, so that we can be sure that there are no trailing whitespaces or another anomalies in the filename.

Comment: What does `errno` or `perror()` say?

Comment: Change `printf("TEST %s\n",y)` to `printf("TEST \"%s\"\n",y)` so we can see if you have any extra spaces in the filename.

Answer (score 1):

Change `printf("TEST %s\n", y)` to `printf("TEST \"%s\"\n", y)` so we can see if you have any extra whitespace characters in the filename.

`fgets()` returns the new line, if it's there. I didn't see where your code clears the newline. Does your path string include the new line?

Beyond that, `fopen()` is almost certainly working correctly. The only options are 1) The path is not correct, 2) the path has whitespace or other invalid characters, or 3) the file is not available for reading.

If you don't have a new line in your path, then you simply haven't provided enough information to resolve this issue.

Comment: Error opening file.
TEST "/Users/Paz/Downloads/Web//WEBINF/classes/org/test/webx/lessons/AbstractLesson.java"

Comment: the output is the same with printf("TEST \"%s\"\n", y)

Comment: Is this Windows? Did you call `GetLastError()` or `erno` to determine the cause?

Comment: Then either the path is not correct, or the file is not available for reading.

Comment: the reason was the newline char. thanks guys i fixed it.

Comment: @Scott: So my original comment to your question 45 minutes ago to add quotes to your test printf call would've resolved this. Welcome to Stackoverflow. You may get a lot of replies to your questions so you should only post when you can actively try the suggestions given to you. And be sure to accept that answer that was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the path, `/Users/lessons/AbstractLesson.java`, is wrong. It looks like an OSX path and it might be missing the username between `Users` and `lessons`.

Comment: @Scott: I don't understand your last comment.

Comment: I deliberately cut the output for confidentiality  reasons.. Do not care about the path , its correct in reality

Comment: @Scott: Oh, you're showing an *approximation* of what's actually happening. I don't think that's a good approach given the nature of the problem. I made some suggestions in the comments to the question. Good luck.

Comment: @Scott: Why am I having trouble believing you about the path being correct? For starters, `fopen()` is well tested and it works. Second, there are many comments asking you to provide more details about the file and you haven't responded to them. The only other alternative is that you have bogus characters as part of your filename, but you haven't provided sufficient information for anyone to determine that.

Comment: @Scott: Make sure `y` doesn't have a trailing newline.

Comment: @Scott: According to another comment of yours, *"the reason was the newline char. thanks guys i fixed it."* This could have been caught by the following suggestion made quite some time ago: *please change the `printf` to `printf("TEST [%s]\n",y)`;*. You've made it remarkably hard for us to help you.